# MonoTouch for iPhone: How to track UIButton's Title text change?

Tags: uibutton, xamarin.ios

Is there is an event fired when a button's title text changed?

I tried ValueChanged or EditingChanged events, but none of them are fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is an event that will capture this. I think your best bet is to subclass UIButton and override the Title method.

Comment: Okay, I tried to do that, but got stuck. The problem is that how do I make use of my subclassed UIButton? Currently, it's decalred in designer.cs, which is auto-generated. If I change it manually, it would be overwritten next time I update the UI in IB. What's proper way to do it?

Comment: You can change the class of the buttons in IB. The first thing to do is add the Register attribute to the top of your subclass with the name of your new button class (i.e. [Register("MyUIButton")]) and don't forget to import MonoTouch.Foundation. This step ensures that IB knows about it. You also need to add some of the constructors that UIButton supports and call the base implementation. Finally, go into IB and in the Identity inspector, select the dropdown arrow next to the Class item and select your custom class.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip. I found a workaround for my problem, but I will try it out later.